# lpc17xx frequency detection of square wave using polling

Tags: algorithm, microcontroller, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller, lpc

I have to read 5 different frequencies(square wave) up to 20KHz by polling 5 different pins.
Im using a single timer interrupt only,for every 1 millisecond.
Polling of the pins would be done in the ISR.

The algorithm i have thought of so far is:
1.Count number of HIGH
2.Count number of LOW
3.Check if sum of HIGH+LOW=Time period.
This algorithm seems slow and is not practical.

Is there any Filter functions that i could use to check the frequency at pin so that all i have to do would be to call that function?
Any other algorithms, for frequency detection would be good.

I am restricted to only 1 interrupt in my code(timer interrupt)

Comment: FYI:im using KEIL uvision if it helps to know

Comment: Polling is a horrible way to do this in any situation. The device should have at least 1 timer with input capture, which is almost perfectly suited for this.

Comment: 1. what kind of signal are you measuring (frequency range,noise) ?  2. what CPU and IO power you have at disposal? 3. why only 1KHz timer?  if your signals are below 100Hz then it is OK but why not measure more precise like with 50KHz or more if your chip can handle it

Answer (score 0):

**you need to take in mind what are the input signal properties**

- as you are limited to just single interrupt (which is pretty odd)
- and the timer has only 1 KHz
- the input signal must not be above 0.5 KHz
- if the signal is with noise the frequency can easily rise above that limit **many times**

**speed**

- you wrote that the simple counting period approach is slow
- what CPU and IO power have you?
- I am used to Atmel AVR32 AT32UC3 chips which are 2 generation before ARM cortex chips
- and I have around 96MIPS and 2-5 MHz pin R/W frequency there without DMA or interrupts
- so what exactly is slow on that approach?

I would code it with your constrains like this (it is just C++ pseudo code not using your platform):

```
const int n=5;
volatile int T[n],t[n],s[n],r[n]; // T last measured period,t counter,s what edge is waitng for?
int T0[n]={?,?,?,...?}; // periods to compare with

void main() // main process
 {
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<n;i++) { T[i]=0; t[i]=0; s[i]=0; r[i]=0; }
 // config pins
 // config and start timer
 for (;;) // inf loop
  {
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)            // test all pins
   if (r[i]>=2)                 // ignore not fully measured pins
    {
    r[i]=2;
    if (abs(T[i]-T[0])>1)     // compare +/- 1T of timer can use even bigger number then 1
     // frequency of pin(i) is not as it should be
    }
  }
 }

void ISR_timer() // timer interrupt
 {
 // test_out_pin=H
 int i;
 bool p;
 for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
  p=get_pin_state(i);                                // just read pin as true/false H/L
  t[i]++;                                             // inc period counter
  if (s[i]==0){ if ( p) s[i]=1; }                   // edge L->H
  else         { if (!p) s[i]=0; T[i]=t[i]; t=0; r[i]++; } // edge H->L
  } 
 // test_out_pin=L
 }
```

- you can also scan as comparation between last pin state and actual
- that would eliminate the need of `s[]`
- something like `p0=p1; p1=get_pin_state(i); if ((p1)&&(p0!=p1)) { T[i]=t[i]; t[i]=0; }`
- this way you can also more easily implement SW glitch filters
- but I think he MCU should have HW filters too (like most MCU does)

**How would I do this without your odd constraints?**

- I would use external interrupt
- usually they can be configured to be trigger on specific edge of signal
- also including the HW filtering of noise
- on each interrupt take the internal CPU clock counter value
- and if it is not at disposal then timer/counter state
- substract with the last measured one
- restore from overflow if occured
- change to `s` or `Hz` if needed
- this way I can scan pins on MCU with 30MHz clock reliably with frequency up to 15MHz (use this for IRC decoder)
- and yes IRC can give you above 1 MHz frequencies on occasions (on edge between states)
- if you want the ratio also the you can:
- have 2 interrupts one for positive and second for negative edge
- or use just one and reconfigure the edge after each hit (Atmel UC3L chips I used some time ago had problem with this one due to internal bugs)

[notes]

- it is essential that the pins you accessing are at the same IO port
- so you can read them all at once and then just decode the pins after
- also the GPIO module is usually configurable so check what clock is it powered with
- there are usually 2 clocks one for interfacing the GPIO module with CPU core
- and the second for the GPIO itself so check both
- you can also use DMA instead of external interrupt
- if you can configure to read the IO port by DMA ... to memory somewhere
- then you can inspect on the background process independent to IO

Comment: @Akshay 1. the ratio of input signal is irrelevant you count whole period  not Low and High parts separately. 2. yes first measurement is invalid you can handle that with additional flags or ignore depends on the usage. after that the measurement is +/-1T off unless noise is present. when you have signals up to 20KHz then you need at least 40KHz timer frequency and I would be more comfortable with at least 50-100KHz just to be sure. anyway the interupt handler is just few instructions so if you do not run on 32KHz CPU clock you should be fine the only problem could be with interfacing GPIO

Comment: @Akshay because I am not familiar with your chip so there can be slowdowns there (interfacing GPIO or reading the pins/port itself) you need to measure the results just poll some output pin in the interrupt and meassure it by Oscilloscope to see how: often,synchronous,long the ISR runs. That should clearly show if this is stable/fast enough ... and you can tweak the frequencies by it

Comment: @Akshay updated the code added additional flag so test is applied only to fully measured signals. btw the edge interrupt approach does also require just single interrupt .... and it require far less CPU and IO power then the polling approach

Comment: @Spektre- i use ISR for multiple other functions like,estimation of time elapsed etc. Frequency reading would be an additional function in the ISR.  My CPU operates at 120Mhz.  The GPIO pins read at 50Mhz max

Comment: @Akshay then just code it and try if it is fast enough but do not forget to increase the timer frequency (1KHz is unusable for your task) if the rest of the ISR needs 1KHz then you can easily set frequency to Nx1KHz and process the rest only each N-th ISR call (one `counter`, one `++` and one `if` needed for this)